# css inline-block centering content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 2 problem with below css

```
#calendarWrap div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 30px;  
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/bononudiju/edit?html,css,output

1. Why the content isn't center completely? It's slightly off down to the bottom, it should be a little bit up. Do I have to adjust the position manually? I know I can using position relative, but is there anyway I can make it center regardless the height and width?
2. Why there's gab between the boxes?

Comment: Do you want the gap or remove it?

Comment: @CarlJan remove it. I don't know why it's there.

Comment: The gap is because of the next-line, try aligning them all, or put a blank comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
#calendarWrap div{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
    line-height:50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div id="calendarWrap">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Basically, replace the padding with `line-height` and in the link you sent, the editor seems to auto space when you hit on the enter button.

Comment: when to use padding? when to use line-height?

Comment: I usually like to use `line-height` to get an accurate middle alignment, but of course, that is not the reason. It just a personal preference of mine. So in your case, you have a height set in pixel, so I prefer to use `line-height` instead. Just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding. Add `line-height: 50px;`.

The gap between the boxes is the physical space in the HTML. Make the parent `font-size: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `float: left;` to your `#calendarWrap div` and change the padding to `padding: 15px 0;`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the gaps, try this:

```
<div id="calendarWrap">
    <div>1</div><!--
 --><div>2</div><!--
 --><div>3</div><!--
 --><div>4</div><!--
 --><div>5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why is this even needed?

Comment: This is to remove the gaps

Answer (score -1):

To remove the space between the elements, remove the white space between the elements. Since those are `inline-block` (treated as `inline`) they will preserve white space inside and between the blocks. And if you want to center the contents inside those boxes horizontally and vertically, the easiest way would probably be to apply `display: inline-flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;`

```css
#calendarWrap div{
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="calendarWrap">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center;`. That's more reproducible.

```css
#calendarWrap>div{
  display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; width:50px;
  height:50px; text-align:center; border:#000 solid 1px;
  border-left:0;
}
#calendarWrap>div:first-child{
  border-left:#000 solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <title>display centered</title>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id='calendarWrap'>
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```